# Is it possible to ensure uniqueness on a sharded hashed key in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, hash, sharding

We need to shard our production DB in a very short timetable, now we have decided to shard on hashed(_id) - however, we have seen it is not possible to create a unique constraint on such an index.

Is it possible in any other way to ensure 100% of the time that we will never insert a duplicate document with the same _id?

We have thought about adding 2 index, 1 for the shard key (hashed(_id)) and a second as the default unique _id index - but we weren't sure if this was possible / would solve our problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enforce-unique-keys-for-sharded-collections/ _thoroughly_.

Comment: tl;dr: ObjectIds are _guaranteed_ to be unique, and a hash collision is less likely than winning the lottery a _lot_ of consecutive times in a row. If you hashed about 6 billion document per second, you would have a 50% chance to create a collision after 100 years. For almost all practical purposes, this should be sufficient.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg - I am aware of that, and I asked if there was a way around it.

Comment: Around what exactly? And what it your current `_id` made up of?

Comment: We currently shard on hashed _id, which is in fact BsonID - and we are aware it's considered as good as any GUID.

However, we have a identification collection that points to the sharded collection, where several various IDs can point to a single _id - that's why we must ensure that the sharded _id will always be unique - as we sometimes will have to manually insert our own BsonIds and there is a possible for duplicate insertion

Comment: Which should not make any difference: such things as host and timestamp are encoded in that value. Using upsert, you'd eliminate any chance of having a duplicate entry with the same id.

Comment: Upsert isn't an option for us on the product end. Let's assume for the sake of the question that the only real solution is making sure 100% that my hashed shard key will always be 100% unique.

Comment: You can't. MD5 is used for hashing. So there is a chance of 1 in 2^128 hashes that they collide.

Comment: The possible options for unique indexes in a sharded cluster are covered [in the manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enforce-unique-keys-for-sharded-collections/). Will #2 work for you?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg The link mentioned in first comment is dead. Can you please update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so our solution was sharding on the _id (which has a forced unique index per Mongod/shard instance) and adding a hashed(_id) index which we sharded on. This ensures that all items are unique.